# JPA Annotated objects as regular Value Objects

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, pojo, value-objects

I have a class that has JPA annotations.. `@Embedded`, `@AttributesOverride`, etc.
Can I use this object as regular POJO / VO? What happens to these annotations then? Are they simply ignored? Or they will still be used / active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely use these POJOs as you want. Just ignore the annotations. They are needed only for persistence of your entities.

Comment: So does that mean, if its called from EntityManager, they are treated as Entity Objects, otherwise, just pojos?